# Pokémon Go Intermittent Mobile Data Connectivity Issue

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm connected to Pokémon Go on mobile data, it crashes so I reboot, but now it won't connect past 1/4 of the loading bar no matter how many times I close and reboot.

However if I turn on my wireless at this point and connect on a wireless router it connects immediately. I can then switch off the wireless connection and maintain the game on my mobile data again.

Comment: Common bug, I think it's got to do with the fact that Pokemon Go, however popular, is still quite the new game and has some patches to go through..

Comment: You'd imagine that they'd be patching daily. Haven't had one in a week. So strange that the bugs aren't uniform on the same devices.

Comment: @FiHoran They've gotta patch those minor text fixes first.